# Is there a word, phrase or coined expression that refers to the x-contains-y relationship?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a specific word, I can think of the word metonym, but it doesn't work for all x-contains-y relationship. For example, dish can refer to the food it contains (metonym), but ship cannot refer to the bolt it contains (never used as a metonym although they're tied by the same logical relationship). So what are some specific words for the x-contains-y relationship?

For example:

> The ship and the bolt are in a ___ relationship whereas the lobster
>   and the dish are in a metonymic relationship.

Comment: This isn't exactly off-topic here, but you would *probably* get better results at EL&U. The precise terminology for metonyms, non-metonyms, and so forth isn't really something that comes up in normal English conversation, and few native speakers would be able to recognize either correct or incorrect terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), the answer would be:

> The ship and the bolt are in a [**"Has-a"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship

or:

> The ship and the bolt are in a **"contains"** relationship

Of course, "has-a" and "contains" are opposites.

---

However, I am not aware of another word, usable for general English, non-OOP contexts.